# 80’s book where people had chips in their brains to do jobs

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

I remember reading a book in the early 80's with the whole chip in the brain theme. You'd goto work, and put a chip in your brain, and you'd get your day's work done. At the end, you'd take the chip out, and do whatever.

The cover had a a picture of the back of a guy's head, with a slot for the chip.

Our hero was given a special assignment, and several chips to use to complete it.

Comment: There is a similar question on a goodreads discussion thread that has some good suggestions that might provide inspiration.  https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/1621097-70s-or-80s-book-about-microchip-implants-in-back-of-the-head

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're thinking of [*The Integrated Man*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?580977) by Michael Berlyn published December 1980 by Bantam Doubleday Dell.  The hero is, essentially trying to organize a rebellion and is on the run, using his supply of chips to stay off the books and ahead of the authorities.  The cover certainly is good match:

[image: Cover of The Integrated Man]

More details [in a review](http://www.williamhertling.com/2013/04/book-review-the-integrated-man/):

> The workers are given implants that allow them to slot a chip (console gaming style) to allow them to do their tasks, essentially turning them into biological robots. The protagonist, fighting to take down the ruthless company head, has his personality embedded on a chip, so that he can go from body to body, and he’s replicated on four chips, so he can exist four times over.

Comment: That's it. Thanks for your time and expertise on this matter.